# JS - clearTimeout vs. delete

Tags: javascript, timer

I am using a timer to call a function after 1 minute.

```
var timer = setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("timer trigger");
}, 10000);
```

**clearTimeout(timer);** clears the timer and **delete timer;** returns **false**.

Why **delete** is not working with timers?

Comment: You may want to read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

Comment: `delete` will delete the object, the `clearTimeout` instead will clear the timer associated to a variable.

Comment: Also, **even if you can** (try without var) delete timer, that won't `clearTimeout` timer.

Comment: `delete` does not close windows or remove DOM elements either.

Comment: "*Why delete is not working with timers?*". Nothing to do with the value, it's because declared global variables can't be deleted using *delete*. See the [*delete operator*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.1), which calls the internal [`[[Delete]]`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12.7) method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`delete timer;` won't actually do anything, because you can only delete object properties. `timer` is not an object property, so it can't be deleted. (Technically it's a property of the window object, but Javascript specifies that unless you assign `window.timer` then you can't delete top level variables). When delete returns `false` that means there was nothing to delete.

The timeout you've set is a function reference. That's what needs to be removed, not the integer returned by `setTimeout`. Only the runtime environment (browser) knows how to remove that function reference by its id, which is what's returned from `setTimeout`.

Comment: *Technically* it's a property of the global object, which is synonymous with the window object, but mostly only in browsers or browser–like environments. ;-)

Comment: we cannot delete function references. But, we can delete top level variables.